# How to stop HTML element getting covered when window resized?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a nav bar and a a div on a website right now. The div is slightly covering the nav bar, however when I resize my window it completely covers the nav bar. I would like it to always somewhat cover the nav bar but not completely.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li class="nav"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="bod">
            <h1 class="title">Home</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#bod {
    height: 100%;
    width: 86%;
    background-color: #F4F3EE;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
right: 0px;
    box-shadow: -1px 0px 10px 1px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 0px 10px 1px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0px 10px 1px #999;}

.nav {
    border: 1px solid #F4F3EE;
    width:20%;
    height:100px;
    color: #F4F3EE;
    margin: 2px 0px 0px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: -1px 0px 10px 1px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 0px 10px 1px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0px 10px 1px #999;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px #F4F3EE;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px #F4F3EE;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px #F4F3EE;
    background: #b58aa5;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ad8599 1%, #b58aa5 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#ad8599), color-stop(100%,#b58aa5));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ad8599 1%,#b58aa5 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ad8599 1%,#b58aa5 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ad8599 1%,#b58aa5 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ad8599 1%,#b58aa5 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ad8599', endColorstr='#b58aa5',GradientType=0 );
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({marginLeft: '-=20px'}, 100);
    $(this).addClass('.nav1');
    });
    $('.nav').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate({marginLeft: '+=20px'}, 100);
    });
});
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what to do make sure the user can still see the nav when the window is resized.

Comment: Please don't use tabs.  You need 4 spaces per line for a code block, and an additional 4 spaces per level.

Comment: Also, shouldn't .nav be used on the list instead of the items in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `left: 200px;` on `#bod`, that will fix it. Then you can get rid of the `width: 86%;` which is set on `#bod` as well. You are absolutely positioning `#bod`, this means that `#bod` is taken out of the regular flow and turned into it's own thing. Now you can set `top`, `left`, `bottom` and `right` to specify the space between the sides of the web page and `#bod`. If you set `bottom: 0px;` on `#bod` you won't need `height: 100%;` on `#bod` either.